# Open a link to different browser

Tags: javascript, web

Is it possible to open google chrome from firefox??
I've already searched but all i can find out is hta or html Application.

here is the code of hta:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openURL()
{
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    shell.run("Chrome http://www.google.com");
}
</script>
```

Are there other solutions for this?
Thanks!

Comment: ActiveXObject is a part of IE's JavaScript only. It is **not** a JavaScript in general and you can't use it in FF or Chrome. And in general it is not possible.

Comment: Thank you! I always thought this is impossible, i guess i just needed a second opinion. Thanks @freakish